# Unable to run JaxRs web service using Wildfly web server

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

Hi I am trying to build a Simple JaxRs web service on JBoss developer studio and Wildfly 11 as application server but i am getting following error while i am trying to deploy my maven project :

> `Failed to start service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/JaxRsTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/JaxRsTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT":
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;`

Also i want to inform you that the project is working fine when i use apache tomcat 9 However it throws above mentioned error when I switch to wildfly 11. I am new to java and Specially web service and just started working for a company which uses Jboss eap server which is quite same as wildfly and unfortunately i am receiving same error there as well while working on a web service assignment.

```
For more reference below is my pom.xml file :

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>JaxRsServiceTest</groupId>
      <artifactId>JaxRsServiceTest</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

and my web.xml file content is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>JaxRsServiceTest</display-name>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.jaxrs.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my java class within package com.test.jaxrs.service is

```
  package com.test.jaxrs.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/test")
public class JaxRsTest {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello/{msg}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String processRequest(@PathParam(value="msg")String message)
    {
        return "Hello : " + message;
    }
}
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong with the wildfly....  and Thanks in advance

Comment: May I suggest that you switch to JBoss EAP?  If you're company is using it - it'd likely benefit you to use the same application server platform.  You can get the [community developer edition](https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/), install the JBoss Tools if you dont already have them and then add the JBoss EAP server.  Which version of EAP is your company using? I use EAP quite a lot and recently got JAX-RS working so I may be able to help you out.  Finally, are you including any specific tomcat related jars in your project as it looks like you may have a no such method error.

Comment: @JGlass my company uses jboss eap 6.1 but i cant install it as its paid version its not free of cost as i read about it on the internet although i have jboss developer studio communit edition but i have no idea about sever can you share an exact link or address for it. And i am not including any tomcat related jars.

Comment: Looks like @stdunbar may have helped out with your question! [Here's](https://developers.redhat.com/download-manager/file/jboss-eap-6.1.0.GA-installer.jar) the link to JBoss EAP 6.1 - they also have 7.1 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly and EAP are a full JEE servers - there is no need to include Jersey dependencies in your `pom.xml`.  Tomcat required that because it is primarily a servlet/JSP engine.  Your service looks good but your `pom.xml` and `web.xml` are the result using Tomcat.  Additionally, you do not need a `web.xml` any longer if you don't want and you certainly don't need to use Jersey to map it.

You'll want one more file - the `Application` class that gets things started.  It looks something like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * Used to bootstrap JAX-RS.  Otherwise this class is
 * not directly used.
 */
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

It can go anywhere in your source tree.  Note that it takes over the `/rest` path which is similar to what you had in your `web.xml`.

The `pom.xml` below will create a .war file that you can deploy to Wildfly.  This is about as simple as it gets and again, remove your `web.xml` for now.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JaxRsServiceTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>JaxRsServiceTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: thanks @stdunbar for your valuable suggestion what ever you suggested is working perfectly...